# Typography elements in material-ui are showing up on the same line

Tags: css, material-ui

For some reason my typography components are continuing on the same line. I have been trying to get them on 2 different lines but its not working.

```
<div class="center">
            <Typography variant="h1" style={{flexGrow: 1}} gutterBottom>line 1</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h6">line 2</Typography>
 </div>
```

Both line 1 and line 2 show up on the same line.

Css for center:

```
.center {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
height: 500px;  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex-direction:column` to your css. Default behavior of flex is to wrap children and use `row` as direction. Or remove the entire flex styles and just use `text-align:center`

Answer (score 0):

According the MaterialIU Typography documentation: https://material-ui.com/system/typography/#typography.
You can wrap text using **Box** component:

```
<Typography component="div" variant="h1">
  <Box>
    line 1
  </Box>
</Typography

<Typography component="div" variant="h6">
  <Box >
    line 2
  </Box>
</Typography>
```